# Bootstrap Column Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I'm replicating a blog template similar to this page https://www.ideo.com/blog

The problem is, I can't get the grids to align the way I need. I've uploaded my version here on this fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/f74d0ngr/9/  *(Make sure you resize the output window to a larger size to understand the issue.)*

I need latest - 2 and latest - 3 posts to align directly under latest - 1.

This is my code

```
<div id="Blog-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8">
              <p class="text-center section-head" id="The-Latest">The Latest</p>
              <img src="img/Blog1.png" alt="" class="blog-img">
              <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h3 class="title">Inviting Algorithms to the Design Team</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4">
              <p class="text-center section-head" id="The-Latest">Most Read</p>
              <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h3 class="">The Best Managers Understand Their Employees’ Emotions—And Their Own</h3>

              <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h3 class="">The Best Managers Understand Their Employees’ Emotions—And Their Own</h3>
              <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h3 class="">The Best Managers Understand Their Employees’ Emotions—And Their Own</h3>
                   <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
              <h3 class="">The Best Managers Understand Their Employees’ Emotions—And Their Own</h3>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p class="text-center section-head" id="The-Latest">The Latest</p>
                <img src="img/Blog1.png" alt="" class="blog-img">
                <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
                <h3 class="title">Inviting Algorithms to the Design Team</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p class="text-center section-head" id="The-Latest">The Latest</p>
                <img src="img/Blog1.png" alt="" class="blog-img">
                <p class="lead less-spacing">Blog | Lorem Ipsum</p>
                <h3 class="title">Inviting Algorithms to the Design Team</h3>

            </div>


        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.section-head{

  background-color: #fbef39;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px; 
}
```

I have tried placing all the sections in different rows, but could not get the alignment I needed. Any suggestions to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sections Latest 2 and Latest 3 in your code should be in `<div class="col-lg-8">` as well as Latest1 but in a different row.
I upadated the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zedqugms/

Comment: Hey, thanks for suggesting ! But I need Latest -2 and 3 to go right below Latest - 1. There is a gap created due to .the most read section

Comment: Hello, sorry I got the question wrong, I updated my answer